# Upload Financial Dimensions on Dynamics Ax

Tags: file-upload, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am a newbie in Dynamics Ax (using 2012 R3) and I'm stuck with the dimensions.

For a list of products, I need to upload their financial dimensions - The Business Unit, Cost Center, Department and the Legal Entity.

Product information management > Common > Released products - *Financial Dimension section*
[image]

The data will be sent to me in a csv file for example or a text file (in case there is a possibility going by DIXF).

At first sight, it seems to me that I'll need to create a job which will accept a csv file and code the insertions.

Any idea how should I proceed?

Is there any possibility of going by DIXF?

Comment: Seems your question has already been answered over in the [AX community](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/177990).

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your problem correctly, you want to import financial dimensions for a number of products through a csv file and you want to know if this is possible through DIXF.

Since the underlying table (InventTable) stores the recID for the financial dimensions in it's field DefaultDimension,  this is not possible, however i think the best approach to solve this would be to write a job , through which you read the content in csv , and update the records in the table where the dimensions are actually stored however there might be issues during the upload since the dimensions are stored across multiple tables. Im not familiar with the task myself and ill check if it can be done.